# Sencha Touch 2 : Populating Tree Store with JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a Nested View bound to a Tree Store.

If I use static data within the store, the view gets populated with this data.

But, If I try to load the store via ajax proxy (JSON), I can see that the store has got the data but the view does not populate this data !

I have been stuck on this for days now. Help !

**Tree Store**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.CategoriesNested', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

    config: {
        model: 'MyApp.model.CategoriesNested',
        defaultRootProperty: 'data',
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        data:[{
        "category_id": 1,
        "text": 'Clothing',
        "data":[{
            "category_id": 11,
            "text": 'Tops and Tees',
            "leaf":true,
        }]
    }, {
        "category_id": 2,
        "text": 'Footwear',
        "data":[{
            "category_id": 22,
            "text": 'Casual Shoes',
            "leaf":true,
        },{
            "category_id": 23,
            "text": 'Sports Shirts',
            "leaf":true,
        }]
    }],
}
});
```

The above works fine. But if i try to load from JSON, this populates the store (inspected the store using chrome web inspector). But the view does not reflect this !

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.CategoriesNested', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

        config: {
            model: 'MyApp.model.CategoriesNested',
            autoLoad: true,
            autoSync: true,
        proxy:{
            type: 'ajax',
            url:'categories.json',
            reader:{
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'data'
            }
        }
}
});
```

**categories.json**

```
{          
    "data": [{
        "category_id": 1,
        "text": 'Clothing',
        "data":[{
            "category_id": 11,
            "text": 'Tops and Tees',
            "leaf":true,
        }]
    }, {
        "category_id": 2,
        "text": 'Footwear',
        "data":[{
            "category_id": 22,
            "text": 'Casual Shoes',
            "leaf":true,
        },{
            "category_id": 23,
            "text": 'Sports Shirts',
            "leaf":true,
        }]
    }]  

}
```

What am i doing wrong ?

**EDIT**

Ok, I realize that if this Nested List is set directly on the viewport, then it shows the data.

But , currently the structure is like this:

Viewport > Tab Panel > Navigation View > Panel > Nested List

Again, the nestedlist shows data when I hardcode the data within the store. But when i read from JSON, it does not show the data. BUT, if I try to set the view directly on the viewport, then the data is shown !

Why does this happen ?

Answer (score 1):

OK solved it. I applied the config
layout: 'fit' 
for the parent panels. This worked.